# Angular2 pipes - Unexpected token <(..)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-directives

I wanted to add pipe for search in my Angular 2 project but the problem is that when i include the created pipe into component browser logs shows me Unexpected token <(..) error.
Full log:

```
    angular2-polyfills.js:332 
Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <(…)
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:332Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:227(anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.js:576Z
oneDelegate.invokeTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:365Zone.runTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:263drainMicroTaskQueue @ angular2-polyfills.js:482ZoneTask.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:434
```

Here is my pipe code:

```
    import {Pipe} from 'angular2/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'SearchPipe'
})

export class SearchPipe {

   transform(items: any[], args: any[]): any {
        return items.filter(item => item.name.indexOf(args[0]) != -1);
   }
}
```

And here is component code.

```
 import { Component, Directive } from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {SearchPipe} from 'pipe/searchpipe';
import 'rxjs/Rx';


@Component({ 
  pipes: [SearchPipe],
  selector: 'MainPage', 
  templateUrl: 'app/mainpage/mainpage.html'
})

export class MainPageComponent { 
    korisnici: Object[];
    constructor(http: Http){
        http.get('korisnici.json')
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(korisnici => this.korisnici = korisnici);
    }
}
```

These error happened for me last time when i was using http without adding http.dev.js library. Is there some JS library for including pipes or i am wrong on something else?

Comment: Are you sure the file where `SearchPipe` is it is called `searchpipe`?

Comment: Yes i have now moved directory of the pipes to app/pipe and now it loads but now i get message TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of null..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Pipe` type is included into `angular2/core` so there is nothing more to add.

That being said, perhaps there is a problem when importing `pipe/searchpipe`. You need to check the path to reach this module from where you want to use it.

Most of time the error `Unexpected token <(…)` occurs on a 404 when loading a module.

Comment: When i type other address then that i get 404 in console log. So the module is loading. I am using Angular 2 (beta 12)

Comment: I have fixed everything. For some reason i needed to move pipe folder into app directory it cannot be seperated from the app.

Comment: In my case I got this error while trying to use Http form angular. In fact I forgot to import http js file like this `<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>`.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the Anglar 2 information on pipes is currently incorrect.

Angular 2 release removed the 'pipes' declaration in: 

`@Component({
    pipes: [YourPipe],
    ...
})`

And moved it to (app.module.ts):

`@NgModule({
    ...
    declarations: [
        YourPipe
    ],
    ...
})`